# How can I set default location for new windows in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, putty

I use Windows 7, and prefer to have the Start menu and taskbar locked to the top of my screen.

However, some windows open underneath the Windows Start bar, so the window minimise, maximise, and close buttons are hidden. Here is an example. You can see that the top of this PuTTY window is completely hidden under the taskbar:

[image: PuTTY window controls hidden under Windows taskbar]

My work-around is to just click the window edge, which causes the window to redraw itself outside the bounds of the taskbar. This works, but I can't help wondering if there's a way to have new PuTTY and other windows automatically draw themselves far enough down the screen that they won't get hidden by the taskbar.

Is it possible to specify the default location for new PuTTY windows, or is there a window manager app I could use to automatically move PuTTY windows down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish moving the 2nd PuTTY window using AutoHotkey.  I used the suggestion from above, but I changed the WinWait command to look for "- PuTTY"

SetTitleMatchMode 2
Run, putty.exe
WinWait, - PuTTY
WinMove, 50, 50

The 1st Putty Window is the configuration screen, which the AutoHotkey Window Spy sees as "PuTTY Configuration"  Then, when you launch your session in PuTTY, this PuTTY window is seen by Window Spy as "your session - PuTTY"

The WinWait command ignores the PuTTY configuration window since it is looking for a window with "- PuTTY"

Answer (score 2):

An [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script like the following may help:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
Run, putty.exe
WinWait, PuTTY
WinMove, 50, 50
```

See details of the *WinTitle* parameter on the [WinMove](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm) page if the window title is not matched properly.

Comment: I installed AutoHotkey and tried it out. When putty.exe launches, the "PuTTY Configuration" selection window appears. From there, you launch a second window (named "PuTTY") that displays the connected server's console, and that's the one that appears beneath the taskbar. AutoHotkey doesn't seem to wait past the "PuTTY configuration" window appearing for the "PuTTY" window to appear. I dabbled with different commands and parameters (WinWaitActive seemed useful) and did move some of my existing windows named PuTTY to 50,50. I need to learn more about AutoHotkey scripting to get it to work.

Comment: AHK is *very* powerful, so there's lots of things you can do. Since the code above is simply searching for "PuTTY" in the window title, it's likely matching the PuTTY Config window itself. As mentioned above, see WinTitle help for the many ways windows can be uniquely identified, such as based on ahk_class shown by Window Spy. You can do other things too, such as have AHK sit in the tray, polling regularly for open (PuTTY) windows and automatically moving them, or running the search+move manually whenever you click the tray icon or run the AHK script... The forum's great for clearing doubts.

Comment: Of course, if all you want is a ready-made solution then AutoSizer's the way to go. Someone already took the time to write and compile an AHK script, so if it does the job and you don't need anything more that AHK can provide, why bother with it?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest and most automated solution that I've found so far is to use freeware app [AutoSizer](http://www.southbaypc.com/AutoSizer/). It's tiny (280 KB) and lives in the system tray and waits for new windows with an appropriate name and class. I created a rule to move every new window named "PuTTY" to the middle of the screen, and now every new PuTTY window appears in the middle of my screen:

[image]

Another option I found was to use the shareware utility app [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/), which has a hotkey shortcut to move any active window to the middle of the screen. You need to ensure that Functions are turned on though (DisplayFusion Settings > Functions > [X] Enable Key Combinations), and then you can press Ctrl + Win + G.

Comment: Ha, looking at the options this program provides, I would pretty much bet it's written using AutoHotkey (the same program I suggested).

Comment: Heh, yes, that's quite possible. I do like the idea of AutoHotkey, and voted your answer up. I want to hold off a bit longer on accepting an answer, to see if anything else falls out. Thanks Karan.

Comment: You're welcome, and feel free to accept whichever solution seems best. Self-answering and self-accepting are both allowed here. (Also, I guess someone downvoted both your answers because you didn't combine them.)

Comment: Ah, no problem. I didn't think to combine answers, as they seemed quite different. Next time I'll know.  (-: